# vue init webpack <my-app> produces 'cd: too many arguments'?

Tags: webpack, terminal, vue.js, vue-cli

It is quite simple. I am trying to create a webpack based vue app. I have done this before with the vue-cli.

I am getting no where.

I have uninstalled vue-cli, reinstalled. I have updated NPM. I have updated brew.

I have read the vue docs, done numerous searches for answers and haven't found a similar error so far.

This is also something that gets produced,

vue init
cd: string not in pwd: /Users/davidjamesmitten/Dev/sites/vue-initial/vue_test_site/todo-app

This directory does not exist. Does anyone have a fix or can they point me in the right direction?

Comment: can you include your package.json?

Comment: I am using the CLI t generate the files. I haven't even for the stage where a JSON file would be generated.

Answer (score 0):

The resolution was simple. All I needed was fresh eyes and brain. I had installed a alias in my .zsh file for 'vue'.

This seemed to be taken as a priority when using 'vue' so any 'vue-cli' or 'vue'v commands would never be implemented.